# How would I create this same effect in adobe illustrator using the pathfinder tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, pathfinder, illustrator-effects

[image: Desired Effect]

I am trying to recreate patterns with a similar style. I have found a way by creating strokes with various widths> blend tool > creating shape (triangle) > dividing > pathfinder > then manually deleting and moving segments...This seems inaccurate and quite tedious

If there is an easier way please let me know....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to manual piecewise deletions nor Pathfinder. Here's a simple receipe:

[image]